# How can i hide particular user from the list using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to hide particular user by clicking on 3 dots icon, Don't know how to hide it. Moreover i want to switch hide tab and Sample tab whenever i want to see.

Here is the code:

```
{Data.map(user => (
          <CardHeader
            key={user.id}
            className={classes.header}
            avatar={<Avatar aria-label="recipe">R</Avatar>}
            action={
              <div className={this.state.menu && classes.menu}>
                <IconButton
                  id="simple-menu"
                  className={classes.showIcon}
                  aria-label="settings"
                  aria-controls="simple-menu"
                  onClick={this.handleClick}
                >
                  <MoreVertIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <Menu
                  style={{ marginTop: "35px" }}
                  id="simple-menu"
                  keepMounted
                  anchorEl={this.state.menu}
                  open={Boolean(this.state.menu)}
                  onClose={this.handleClose}
                >
                  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>View</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>hide</MenuItem>
                </Menu>
              </div>
            }
            title={user.title}
            subheader={user.subheader}
          />
        ))}
```

[Here is the sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-menu-button-visibility-fix-8mwki)

Can anyone please help me in this query?

Comment: use onClick and make your flag false.

Comment: @sushildlh - Hi, Could you please assist me where do i give flag as false

Comment: Sure. What you have to hide in that card?

Comment: @sushildlh - Actually, in sample.json we have 2 users details. in Sample.js i'm retrieving those users. by clicking on the user's dot icon. there are 2 options in the dot icon. the second option is hide

Comment: there is 2 user but there isn't hide. Its unhide.

Comment: @sushildlh - Hi, I've updated my code in codesandbox. Could you please preview the code once? once hover on the User, we could see three dots(once make ishide: false) then you could see the users

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214711/discussion-between-sushildlh-and-sanjana).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these in your code...

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Sample from "./Sample";
import Hide from "./Hidden";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isHide: false };
  }

  onHandleHide = () => {
    this.setState({ isHide: false });
  };

  onHandleshow = () => {
    this.setState({ isHide: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!this.state.isHide ? (
          <Hide onShow={this.onHandleshow} />
        ) : (
          <Sample onHide={this.onHandleHide} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

In Hidden.jsx add this line.

```
<MenuItem onClick={this.props.onShow}>Unhide</MenuItem>
```

and Sample.jsx file add this line.

```
<MenuItem onClick={this.props.onHide}>hide</MenuItem>
```

I hope your problem solve.

Here is [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-menu-button-visibility-fix-y7by3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: this one works perfectly fine but i've updated the code... for the code, this solution isn't working....Can we send same as props to 2 children

Comment: just go through the code and do those changes it is too simple.

Comment: Yes sure, i'll try